# fancyBox 3 afterShow not working when trigger is created by ajax

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to fire a function after fancyBox popup is loaded:

```
jQuery("[data-fancybox='car']").fancybox({
    afterShow: function() {
        console.log('check me');
    }
});
```

It works only when the trigger of the popup is created normally (i.e. on page load), but if the trigger of fancyBox is loaded with ajax, afterShow does not console the `'check me'` text.

This is the trigger:

```
<a data-fancybox="car" data-type="ajax" data-src="<?php echo home_url();?>/?car_card=<?php echo $post->ID;?>" href="javascript:;">
    fancyBox Trigger - content is loaded fine, but afterShow does not fire when the trigger is created by ajax. 
</a>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are initializing fancyBox before your content exists, then

1) check out the documentation - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage and

2) try something like this:

```
$().fancybox({
  selector  : '[data-fancybox="car"]',
  afterShow : function() { console.log('check me'); }
});
```